# C++ Newbie question: ThreadProc

Tags: c++

I am just trying to understand some source code written in C++. I am a bit familiar
with C++, however, the following code sequence is absolutley new to me. A guess would be
that here I register some thread routine with the kernel, ptest->Run(). Could that be right?

```
static unsigned int __stdcall ThreadProc(void *lParameter)  
{  
CTest *ptest;  

ptest= (Ctest *)lParameter;  
ptest->Run();  
return 0;  
 }  


CTest::CTest(int n)  
{  
...  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit simplified but a thread is a function, in this case ThreadProc. When the thread starts, the function is called and when the function exits the thread dies.

In this case, someone has started a thread with CreateThread, begin_thread or something else and passed in a pointer to a class called CTest as an argument. The thread then casts it back to a CTest* (as you can see the argument is delivered by the CreateThread API as a more generic void*) and calls the CTest::Run method before exiting.

**Edit:** Also, except for the "__stdcall" declaration, this is not very Windows specific. Threads in C and C++ works more or less like this on all OSes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a function signature that would be used to define a function that is exported from a DLL or used as a callback function.  In this case it is probably going to be used a the main loop of a worker thread.

the `__stdcall` keyword indicates that the function call is passed on the stack using the [stdcall calling convention in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) (same as used by methods exported from the Win32 API)

OOPS:  this link doesn't play nice with markdown `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(VS.80).aspx`

Comment: Fixed the link for you; the (VS.80) part isn't significant in MSDN URLs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. This is your thread function:

```
static unsigned int __stdcall ThreadProc(void *lParameter)
```

It will be executed an different thread than whatever caused it. Calling code creates an object of type CTest, creates a thread that runs ThreadProc, which in turn runs ptest->Run();

ThreadProc is just a convenience wrapper to launch ptest->Run(). (Because otherwise it is kinda hard to use pointers to member functions)

Answer (score 0):

What OS? Looks like a Windows sample, if so begin_thread(), or CreateThread or...several

Answer (score 0):

The code you show declares a pointer to a CTest class object, converts the input parameter into one of those, then calls its run method.

The *why* this is done is the tricky part. Normally you wouldn't write code like this, however, the profile of ThreadProc is that of a thread's main entry point. For one of those, Windows doesn't give you any choice for the parameter profile of it, and it can't be a class member.

What you have there is fairly standard code to convert a thread entry-point callback from the Windows' required form into a class method call.

For a full discussion of this, see my (accepted) answer for the question: [Passing Function pointers in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402992/passing-function-pointers-in-c/403140#403140)