# C++ accessing a function from in a class, receiving functions as a parameter

Tags: c++, function

i have two questions that are fairly small and related so i will put them both in the same question.

i have been experimenting with classes and i was attempting to access a class in another file that wasn't in a class so for example.

```
//class 1 .cpp
void Class1::function1()//another error 
{
    function()
}


//main.cpp

void function()
{
//stuff happens
}
```

is there a way to-do this? or would i need to add this function to a class to get it to work. also how would you go about creating a function that receives a function as it parimetre? for example `function(function2())`

i am simply trying to access a function from a class as it would make my code easier to use later if the function that i am using doesn't get added to a class. with regards to the seconds question i which to create a function that receives a time and a function as an argument. it will wait for the specified time then execute the program

Comment: Can you please ask this question in the context of an issue you are attempting to overcome?

Comment: For your second question, there are other questions on StackOverflow about how to pass function *pointers* in C++. Here is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402992/passing-function-pointers-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***How to access a function in another file?***
Depends on the type of function, there can be to cases:

***1.  Accessing class member functions in another file(Translation Unit):***
Obviously, you need to include the header file, which has the class declaration in your caller translation unit.

***Example code:***

```
//MyClass.h

class MyClass
{
    //Note that access specifier
    public:
        void doSomething()
        {
             //Do something meaningful here
        }

};

#include"MyClass.h"    //Include the header here
//Your another cpp file
int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

***2.  Accessing free functions in another file(Translation Unit):***

You do not need to include the function in any class, just include the header file which declares the function and then use it in your translation unit.

***Example Code:***

```
//YourInclude.h

inline void doSomething() //See why inline in @Ben Voight's comments
{
    //Something that is interesting hopefully
}

//Your another file

#include"YourInclude.h"

int main()
{
    doSomething()
    return 0;
}
```

Another case as pointed out by @Ben in comments can be:
***A declaration in the header file, followed by a definition in just one translation unit***

***Example Code:***

```
//Yourinclude File
void doSomething();  //declares the function

//Your another file
include"Yourinclude"
void doSomething()   //Defines the function
{
    //Something interesting
}

int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternately, a messy way to do this can be to just mark the function as extern in your another file and use the function.Not recommended but a possibility so here is how:

***Example Code:***

```
extern void doSomething();

int main()
{
    doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

***How would you go about creating a function that receives a function as it parameter?***
By using `function pointers`
In a nutshell Function pointers are nothing but pointers but ones which hold address of functions.

***Example Code:***

```
int someFunction(int i)
{
    //some functionality
}


int (*myfunc)(int) = &someFunction;


void doSomething(myfunc *ptr)
{
    (*ptr)(10); //Calls the pointed function

}
```

Comment: Functions should only be defined in a header if they are marked `inline` -- your example 2 is bad practice.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Rightly said! I am going to modify that bit rightaway.

Comment: That's good (+1), but you might also want to give an example of the more common case: A declaration in the header file, followed by a definition in just one translation unit.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Done, that completes it!

Comment: great answer you covered all the questions i asked +1 and accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

You need a prototype for the function you want to call.  A class body contains prototypes for all its member functions, but standalone functions can also have prototypes.  Typically you organize these in a header file, included from both the file which contains the function implementation (so the compiler can check the signature) and in any files which wish to call the function.

Comment: THANK YOU... i keep forgetting about function prototypes :D it works now...do u have any ideas how i would acomplish the second part of the question?

Comment: @Phantasm: For the second part, you need to tell us what platform.  The standard C/C++ libraries have some system clock functions but no wait functions, you'll need to use something OS-specific or an external library such as `boost::asio` which provides timers.

Comment: no you miss understood the question i already have a fully functional timer i wish to no how i can have a function as argument for another question

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) How can the `class` function be accessible ?
```

You need to declare the `class` body in a header file and `#include` that wherever needed. For example,

```
//class.h
class Class1 {
  public: void function1 (); // define this function in class.cpp
};
```

Now `#include` this into main.cpp

```
#include"class.h"
```

You can use `function1` inside main.cpp.

```
(2) How to pass a function of class as parameter to another function ?
```

You can use pointer to class [member functions](http://www.goingware.com/tips/member-pointers.html).

Comment: Thats incorrect! `function1()` has a private access specifier in `Class1` here which makes it pretty much useless to be called in another translation unit!

Comment: @Als: access specifiers have nothing to do with translation units.

Comment: @Ben Voight: Probably I was not clear enough the point is If `function1()` is private, How can it be called from outside the class?

Comment: @Als: You didn't say "outside the class", you said "another translation unit".  Classes and translation units are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: My wordings were a bit mumbled on that, still dizzy i guess! It wont work even in the same translation unit, So Yes, it has nothing to do with translation unit but nevertheless it is incorrect!

Comment: @Als, I had copy pasted the code from the OP so missed the `public`. Have edited it.