# Threading in C

Tags: c

I want to create a thread in C so that the thread automatically call after two seconds. I am using Visual Studio and Windows platform for development.

How do I get started?

Comment: What platform? And what do you mean, "automatically call"? Should the thread automatically call a function after a two-second timeout? Do you need this to be a separate thread, or would a timer in the same thread be sufficient? Try being a bit more specific in your question.

Comment: I m using visual studio 2008 and window platform for the development. And automatically call means that I want to recursively call the thread after every 2 seconds, just like NSTimer function in objective c.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are going to need to use OS specific libraries to do threading.  On Posix, you will want to look into [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) (and specifically [pthread_create](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create)).  On Windows, you'll want [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx) or _[beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).

Comment: The new C standard, C11 includes [multi-threading support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread)

Answer (score 4):

Multithreading in C is platform dependent. You need to use external libraries corresponding to different platforms.

Read about:

[Multithreading in C, POSIX style](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.c.php)  and [Multithreading with C and Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6h8hye8(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in standard C that could help you. You need to use some library or platform-dependent features. Don't forget that many platforms simply don't have threads - only full-weight processes.

On Windows use [CreateThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx). You'll need Microsoft SDK to compile your code using this and other Win32 functions.

Comment: Kindly tell me some libraries which can make it possible.

Comment: I suggest you specify the target platform requirements first - I could tell a library that is not suited for the platform of your interest.

Comment: Kindly tell us your platform, Arman...On Unix, you would normally use the POSIX pthread library; on Windows, you use the native Windows threading API.

Answer (score 2):

C doesn't have built in threading facilities; you will have to use your OS services to create a thread.

For windows use [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this link for different ways to do it:
[Windows threading: _beginthread vs _beginthreadex vs CreateThread C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c)

For cross-platform code, you can also check the [Boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) or [Intel Threading Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to MSDN for VC8. Refer to the createThread() help there. That should give you sufficient information.

For checking online, please go the link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample program for Single Threading and Multithreading in Win32API written in C will work on Visual studio.

**SingleThread.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI funHello(void *x)
{
    int c = (int*)x;
    printf("\n Thread No: %d\n",c);
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE  myhandle;
    DWORD threadId;
    int c = 1;
    myhandle = CreateThread(NULL, 0, funHello, (void *)c, 0, &threadId);
    if (myhandle == NULL)
    {
        printf("Create Thread Failed. Error no: %d\n", GetLastError);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(myhandle, INFINITE);
    printf("\n Main Hello...\n");
    CloseHandle(myhandle);
    return 0;
}
```

**MultiThreading.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2     //  Define Number of threads here or take as user Input, 
                          // In yourquestion it is 2

DWORD WINAPI funHello(void *x)
{
    int c = (int*)x;
    printf("\n Thread No: %d\n",c);
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    HANDLE *arrayThread;
    arrayThread = (int*)malloc(NUM_THREADS * sizeof(int));
    DWORD ThreadId;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        arrayThread[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, funHello, (void *)i, 0, &ThreadId);
        if (arrayThread[i] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Create Thread %d get failed. Error no: %d", i, GetLastError);
        }
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM_THREADS, arrayThread,TRUE,INFINITE);
    DWORD lpExitCode;
    BOOL result;

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(arrayThread[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Hello Main..");
    return 0;
}
```