# Boost library and CreateThread win API

Tags: multithreading, winapi, boost, boost-thread, createthread

I  have a class such as :

```
class MyStreamReader
{
public:
    MyStreamReader(MyPramameter myPram) {.....}
    ~MyStreamReader() {}

    DWORD WINAPI  ReaderThread(LPVOID *lpdwThreadParam ) 

    {

       //....
    }
};
```

and i want to call  ReaderThread with **WinAPI CreateThread**. **But CreateThread wants  ReaderThread function wants a static function.**

**In some forms it is said that this is possible with boost library such as** :

```
CreateThread(NULL, 0, boost::bind(&MyStreamReader::ReaderThread,this),

(void*)&myParameterObject), 0, NULL);
```

But i got compilation error:

```
'CreateThread' : cannot convert parameter x from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>' 

to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'
```

**So as a result my questions:**

1. Is it possible to call non-static function of a class from
   CreateThread using boost lib(or any other method)
2. If not any C++ THREADing librray you may recomend(for visual C++) which i can call-run non static member function of a class as a thread?

Best Wishes

**Update:**

So first question: It seesm that it is impossible to call non-static c++ member function from CreateThread win API...

So any recomandations for C++ Multithreading lib whic is possible to call  non-static functions as threads...

**Update 2:**
Well i try boost thread lib...seems it works...

```
MyStreamReader* streamReader = new MyStreamReader(myParameters);


boost::thread GetStreamsThread

   ( boost::bind( &MyStreamReader::ReaderThread, streamReader ) );
```

or (no need for bind)

```
boost::thread GetStreamsThread(&MyStreamReader::ReaderThread, streamReader);
```

AND in order to use boost::thread i update my class definition as:

```
class MyStreamReader
  {
    public:
        MyStreamReader(MyPramameter myPram) {.....}
        ~MyStreamReader() {}

        void ReaderThread()
        {

           //....
        }
  };
```

Comment: Stay away from `CreateThread` and use `_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex` if you really have to. Those are too low level functions to deal with threads. Just listen to @Kaz Dragon.

Comment: @sad_man Why is `_beginthread` better than `CreateThread`?

Comment: @David: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/331536/425817) is enough for me unless you have something to say.

Comment: @sad_man _beginthread  is a good alternative for non static c functions BUT sucks at C++ member functions...

Comment: @sad_man those problems with using the C runtime from threads created by `CreateThread` have been fixed in recent versions of the runtime. It was a ludicrous limitation anyway. What if you want to run code in a thread that was created by some other module?

Comment: @6.45.Vapuru biraderim, I do not understand what you mean by "sucks" BUT _C++ member functions_ title is a different story. `_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` do almost the things, except that you do not use `CloseHandle()` with the handle returned by _beginthread. It is automatically closed.

Comment: @David, hmmmm I don't know please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common answer to this is to use a static "thunk":

```
class Worker
{
    public :
        static DWORD Thunk(void *pv)
        {
            Worker *pThis = static_cast<Worker*>(pv);
            return pThis->DoWork();
        }

        DWORD DoWork() { ... }
};

...

int main()
{
    Worker worker;
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Worker::Thunk, &worker);
}
```

You can, of course, pack more parameters into your call to pv.  Just have your thunk sort them out correctly.

To answer your question more directly, boost::bind doesn't work with the Winapi that way.  I would advise using boost::thread instead, which does work with boost::bind (or, if you have a C++0x compiler, use std::thread with std::bind).