# correctly terminate a running thread which "works"

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, createthread

I have a thread like this:

```
DWORD WINAPI message_loop_thread(LPVOID dummy) {
        MSG message;
        while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0)) {
                TranslateMessage(&message);
                DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
}
```

And i start it with `CreateThread`:

```
DWORD thread_id;
CreateThread(0, 0, message_loop_thread, 0, 0, &thread_id);
```

This seems to work, but how can i correctly close this thread? Normally the thread is waiting for `GetMessage` so the thread is blocked i think.

Is there a good way to do this? I tried `TerminateThread`, but this hangs, and i think it's not a good solution to stop the thread.

Has someone an idea?

best regards
Benj Meier

Comment: Do not use `CreateThread()` unless you are aware of what it does *not* do. `CreateThread()` does not initialize the runtime properly, nor does it set up CRT finalization hooks to execute when the thread dies. See a discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to post `WM_QUIT` to `thread_id`. You use `PostThreadMessage()` for this. In response, `GetMessage` returns 0, the `while` loop exits, and the function exits (incorrectly, you're missing a `return` statement). When the toplevel function of a thread exits, the thread ends.