# C++ - Passing an object to CreateThread() by ref

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm not sure what the correct syntax is for this because it involves the winapi which i'm not familiar with. For example, i didnt know it won't let me xhangethe predefined thread function parameters from processClient(LPVOID) to processClient(LPVOID&).

I need to pass the "params" object by reference(just so theres no problems for now, even though im not going to change values in it) to the thread function "processClient()".

```
... struct(the object) declaration
struct ClientParams{

    ClientParams::ClientParams():sock(INVALID_SOCKET), i(NULL){};

public:
    SOCKET sock;
    int i;
};

... in processClient(LPVOID lpParam){
    SOCKET ClientSocket=(SOCKET)*lpParam->sock; ?? doesnt work
    int i=*lpParam->i; ?? doesn't work
}
... in main{
ClientParams *params = new ClientParams();
params->i=some_value;
params->sock=ClientSocket;
CreateThread(
            NULL,                       // don't inherit handle
            0,                          // use default size for the executable
            processClient,
            (LPVOID)params,             // thread data
            0,                          // run right away
            &i );
}
```

Comment: I suggest using `std::thread` instead for ease, but it's already a pointer, so just pass in a pointer to what you need and convert it to the same pointer inside.

Comment: `SOCKET ClientSocket = ((ClientParams*)lpParam)->sock;` - basic C++. Maybe a multithreaded networking application is not the best fit for a first project.

Comment: @IInspectable, You're dereferencing a void pointer. Anyway, you mean C. C++ really does have better ways than void pointers.

Comment: @chris You cannot use C++ when calling a C API...

Comment: @IInspectable, I mean the method of using void pointers as data parameters, though. It originated from C, and I cannot think of a time when I'd rather do that than use a safer and easier C++ method of accomplishing the same thing. Thus, I compare this to learning C strings instead of `std::string`, or manual memory management instead of RAII-based utilities. One is obviously a lot more C-like and C++ programmers don't generally do things that way. In any case, the most C++ way for this specific task is the standard threading library, which also does the data parameters in a better way.

Comment: @chris This question is tagged [winapi]. The most C++ way for this specific task is to call a C interface. And since this question is tagged [winapi] the standard threading library is certainly a **lot** less capable than the native synchronization primitives.

Comment: @IInspectable, A lot less capable? A simple line to create the object and pass in the data, whatever functions it has, and then you can get the `HANDLE` for it any time you need to do anything it doesn't offer (although Boost's has `interrupt` and whatnot). It's a lot simpler on the outside and being able to get the handle allows for anything possible with winapi calls to happen as well.

Comment: @IInspectable, Anyway, it certainly is possible to use C++ to some extent when dealing with a C API. The thread handle is one example, but also consider using a vector, passing the direct memory instead of the vector itself, and continuing with what you were using it for before. The question is also tagged C++, so I don't see why standard C++ automatically doesn't apply. For all I know, the OP would love `std::thread`, but never knew it existed.

Comment: CreateThread shouldn't be used as it leaks, also you are leaking the handle it returns, and not checking if creating the thread actually worked

Comment: @paulm `CreateThread` does not leak. What makes you think it would? And what would you propose instead? And how does this proposed superior alternative - which eventually calls `CreateThread` itself - magically remove the leakage from an API it does not control?

Comment: It causes a leak if you're using the CRT - which most people do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c

Comment: @paulm `_beginthreadex` calls `CreateThread`. So if `CreateThread` causes a leak, then so does `_beginthreadex`. Neither is true. `_beginthread[ex]` is required to set up per-thread state, like `errno`, locale, floating point environment, etc.. Failure to call `_beginthread[ex]` does not cause a leak. It simply invokes undefined behavior, when calling one of the CRT functions that require per-thread state.

Comment: CreateThread() won't leak, but there will still be a memory leak: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104641/en-us

Comment: @paulm So in other words: The **CRT** leaks memory when used on a thread that wasn't prepared to run code from the CRT. This doesn't come as much of a surprise. Calling `CreateThread` is perfectly safe, and sound, and never leaks.

Comment: Since he *is* using the CRT he has a memory leak, therefore in any normal win32 app that uses the CRT I wouldn't say its "safe and sound" since its usage will cause a memory leak.

Comment: @paulm Kudos for reading the OP's mind. I do not see the definition of `processClient` so I cannot possibly know whether or not he is running CRT code on the thread. The point is: `CreateThread` does not leak and is not inherently unsafe. If you want to use the CRT however, make sure to play by the rules.

Comment: He is using operator new, so I don't need to read his mind, operator new is provided by the CRT.

Comment: @paulm You misinterpret the rules. The rules are that you must initialize the CRT on a thread, **if that thread uses the CRT**. `operator new` is not called on the thread in question; the call to `CreateThread` can be perfectly safe. With the information provided we don't know for sure, one way or another. Aside: `operator new` is not provided by the CRT. However, it calls `malloc` and can throw exceptions - both of these are implemented in the CRT.

Comment: What provides operator new? If I build apps without a CRT I have to define my own, usually calling HeapAlloc().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43836/discussion-between-iinspectable-and-paulm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> SOCKET ClientSocket=(SOCKET)*lpParam->sock; ?? doesnt work

lpParam has the same value it did when you passed it, in main, where it was 'params', of type 'ClientParams*', so you don't have any business dereferencing it with '*'. The rest of it is just a precedence problem. It should be

```
SOCKET ClientSocket=((ClientParams*)lpParam)->sock;
```

Comment: Thanks! The void parameters in the winapi confused me.

Answer (score 0):

Access structure members must through the structure.

```
SOCKET ClientSocket=((ClientParams*)lpParam)->sock;
```