# C++: Which API is recommended for implementing threading model in a windows application

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-safety, createthread

I have a C++ application which needs to be multi-threaded in windows platform. After browsing some forums, I gave `CreateThread` API a try. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the link giving details regarding its signature.

But, it always throws `Access violation` error and after going through some more forums, I got a bit confused when they said that this API has always had some problems. Some have recommended to use `BeginThreadEx`.

What is your recommendation for threading model implementation? Also, give reasons for your recommendation.

Comment: "...they said that this API has always had some problems..." I think there were definitely problems involved, but I have doubts their origins were with the Windows API. There are *runtime* library issues that historically needed accounting for proper setup of MS CRT (thats likely the `_beginthreadex` you're referring to). You may find [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c) an interesting read.

Comment: The [`CreateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function is the native way of creating threads on Windows. No matter which other API you use, in the end there's going to be a call to `CreateThread` if you're on Windows.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the link to the question!

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, why not use `std::thread`, it's much cleaner and is cross-platform.

Comment: @DavidOtano Yeah..but sadly, C++11 is still not supported here

Comment: @Joachim well I could theoretically use the actual nt calls amd and it ;) but really I can't think of a single reason to use CreateThread.