# PostMessage(), SendMessage not working in ATL dll (event handling)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, event-handling, atl

sorry, my english skill is very low.

i make a ATL(C++) dll. and handled by VB.
i make under base code.

WaitAndReadData, Thread_WaitAndReadData is working.

but, ::SendMessage, ::PostMessage is not working in Thread_WaitAndReadData or WaitAndReadData.
and breakpoint not working in Get_Data_Messagehandler.
(+ another function call.)

```
#define WM_SERVERTHREADFIREEVENT (WM_USER+2)
BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CHello)
CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CComControl<CHello>)
MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SERVERTHREADFIREEVENT, GetData_Messagehandler)
DEFAULT_REFLECTION_HANDLER()
END_MSG_MAP()
```

-

```
static DWORD WINAPI Thread_WaitAndReadData(LPVOID pParam)
```

-

```
STDMETHODIMP CHello::WaitAndReadData(BSTR* ret_Result)
{
    // TODO: Add your implementation code here

    DWORD dwThreadID;

    thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread_WaitAndReadData, (LPVOID)this, 0, &dwThreadID);

    return S_OK;
}
```

-

```
DWORD WINAPI CHello::Thread_WaitAndReadData(LPVOID pParam)
{

CHello* hello = (CHello*)pParam;

::SendMessage(hello->m_hWnd, WM_SERVERTHREADFIREEVENT, (WPARAM)NULL, (LPARAM)NULL);

return S_OK;
}
```

-

```
LRESULT CHello::GetData_Messagehandler(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
{
MessageBox(L"GetData_Messagehandler", L"asd", MB_OK);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Even though MSDN states that there is no marshaling of `WM_USER + x` messages in cross-process sending, if my memory serves me right you might have troubles with cross-thread sending as well. In this case use `RegisterWindowMessage` API to obtain "sendable" `WM_xxx` identifier rather than harcoding it using a `#define`
2. Don't use bare `CreateThread`, use `AtlCreateThread` instead (or, `_beginthreadex`). [See why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c).

Another reason to not receive messages on window thread is thread deadlock or window creation on thread that does not have a message pump later on, in both cases a message might be sent but there is no dispatching it to window. You can also use Spy++ tool (spyxx.exe in Visual Studio Comment\Tools directory) to make sure that the message in question is indeed being sent to the window.