# Is this the right way to start a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

This is the method i use to start threads and it works, but I wonder are there any downsides to this way.

```
void myFunc()
{
    //code here

}


unsigned int _stdcall ThreadFunction(void* data)
{
    myFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

I my main function i use :

```
HANDLE A = (HANDLE)_beginthredex(0,0,&ThreadFunction,0,0,0);
```

And I end the thread  with `CloseHandle(A);`.

Comment: `#include <thread>`. Use the C++ STL's `thread` library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to C++11 use the [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) library and you won't need to worry about cross-platform compatibility:

```
#include <thread>

std::thread t(&ThreadFunction, nullptr);
```

To wait for the thread's execution to finish, use `join()`:

```
t.join();
```

This blocks until the function that the thread is supposed to run has returned.

Otherwise, use [CreateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx) (since it looks like you're on Windows) or [beginthreadex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx).

For POSIX, use [`pthread_create()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html).

Comment: On Windows [`_beginthreadex` might have some advantages over `CreateThread`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331536/windows-threading-beginthread-vs-beginthreadex-vs-createthread-c), like supporting thread_local variables.